# A dynamic data structure to list triangles

Tags: graph-theory, ds.data-structures

Consider an undirected graph with $n$ nodes.  Is there an efficient data structure that supports the following operations?

- Insert an edge into the graph
- Delete an edge from the graph
- Given a query edge $(i,j)$, list all the triangles that include that edge. There can be $n$ of these in the worst case but ideally this operation would be sublinear if the number of triangles to be reported is.

Comment: I haven't looked at it very closely, but maybe the techniques in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02780 can be used for your kind of queries?

Comment: Is the graph sparse or dense? (Or can be any?)

Comment: @CyriacAntony It can be any as you suggest.